# Server side BrainTree credit card tokenizer

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, braintree

From [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/credit-cards) I know I can generate a token for a credit card, but I couldn't be able to find any documents regarding generate the token from the server-side. If I think correct about this, passing the token to the server from the client JS is a noticeable security bug.

```
token = client.tokenizeCard({
  number: '4111111111111111',
  // or expirationMonth and expirationYear
  expirationMonth: '10',
  expirationYear: '2015',
  // CVV if required
  cvv: '832'
}, function(e, nonce) {
    console.log([e, nonce]);
});
```

#### Question:

How can generate a credit card's token in from the server-side?

Comment: They already said here and recommend method of verification [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#card-verification)

Comment: @DavidJawHpan Noope, it's not!

Comment: I think it doesn't have verify method like client , they recommend to use control panel before access in server side ..